# Display a vertical line after the line numbers in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

How can I make Atom display a vertical line after the line numbers, so that I know where the lines start?

Here's how it looks now:

[image: Before]

Here's how I want it to look:

[image: After]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your Atom Stylesheet:

```
.gutter-container {
    border-right: 1px solid #555;
}

.scroll-view {
    margin-left: 6px;
}

.vertical-scrollbar {
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

Result:

[image: Vertical line after line numbers]